# Dockerise Laravel / VueJS application

Tags: php, laravel, docker, npm

I have a laravel app that I want to dockerise.

I have seen several tutorials, like: 
https://medium.com/@pierangelo1982/dockerize-an-existing-laravel-application-with-docker-compose-a45eb7956cbd

https://kyleferg.com/laravel-development-with-docker/

https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c

https://www.codementor.io/patrickfohjnr/developing-laravel-applications-with-docker-4pwiwqmh4

Here is my Dockerfile for dev:

```
FROM php:7.1.14-fpm

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git npm \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
&& curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
&& touch ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less \
&& apt-get purge --auto-remove -y g++ \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& composer install && php artisan key:generate && php artisan migrate:fresh  --seed \
&& npm cache clean -f && npm install -g n && n stable && npm install cross-env && npm install && npm run dev
```

There is 1 thing I don't understand:

Should I install all my dependencies ( composer install + npm install ) in the container ? It seems necessary to me even if it makes me a 1GB image, and it is quite long to build but a lot of those tutorials don't do it. How can it work?

Note: I don't want to use laradock, as the goal is to learn and practice Docker.

Comment: I don't install dependencies in the image itself, only the necessary build tools. Then within the container I'll install composer and npm dependencies. Odds are you'll end up changing/updating `composer.json` and `package.json` so its better to not install everything directly into the image and save the build time/image size.

Comment: Actually I am new in docker too. But on my daily usages, I install the dependencies inside the container. Why, because in the container we have been define and have a version of php installed. The dependecies should based on the php inside the container right? If I run on the host, it may have different php version.

Comment: @btl composer.json will not change, do you mean composer.lock ? But then you can't deploy you container directly without each time executing composer install, etc... am I wrong ?

Comment: Yep, the containers are meant to be isolated environments with all the necessary dependencies. You can certainly run into trouble by running on the host versus within the container

Comment: It depends on your deployment strategy. I have installed new packages between between releases as well as removed obsolete/deprecated ones so `composer.json` did change.

Comment: it seems that if you don't download dependencies in your dockerfile, you will lose deployability ( if this word even exists )

Answer (score 0):

there is no sense in establishing dependencies within. just call the command line of your container and run the dependency setup

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
```